# Android OnTextChanged one array-list with two ways

Tags: android, search, textview, cyrillic

I have an ArrayList with words in Ukrainian (using cyrillic alphabet) that I show in a ListView using an adapter. I have a TextView which I'm using to search for the words in the ArrayList, and it works fine (using `OnTextChanged()`).

What I want to do is to add another way to search for the words of that same list, but using our alphabet. That'd be searching for the word "добре" by writing "добре" or "dobre".

Here's the code I am using:

```
cuadroBusqueda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busqueda);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


final ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries));


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Country Name", listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

cuadroBusqueda.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

And then, I have the XML with the items. I need it to be like that for the moment because I have a second activity using that ArrayList.